# @font-face custom font not rendering properly with xhtml2pdf for django

Tags: html, css, django, font-face, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to use a custom font in my attempts to render a pdf from HTML.

I've tried it out in HTML, the font shows up, so the path to the font must be correct, and it's probably being used correctly.  The font is of type .ttf, and according to the docs on http://xhtml2pdf-base.googlecode.com/hg/doc/xhtml2pdf-en.html, it should render, but it doesn't.

Here's what I have in my style tags:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Swiss";
  src: url("/static/font/swiss.ttf");
}
body {
  font-family: "Swiss";
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

And the html:

```
<body>
  asdf
</body>
```

I've tried many things, stripping the quotes off the font url and font family, my body is wrapped inside HTML tags so the html is properly formatted.  Everything renders fine when rendering in a web page, but it's not being rendered properly when converting to PDF.  Can anyone help me spot the error?

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use a callback to fetch fonts using filesystem path. Is more accurate and also you wan't be hitting webserver for each resource (resource meaning, fonts, images, etc)

```
pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode("UTF-8"), file_object , encoding='UTF-8',
               link_callback=fetch_resources)

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    find_file_in_path_using_uri
    return path
```

By the way, I think your problem is you haven't done collect static so fonts are not really at /static/font/swiss.ttf. I mean they are not there outside django, and xhtml2pdf it's outside django. I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Last paragraph..... Genius!!! xD

Comment: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-pdf/) This is the right way to create and/or serve pdf files though...

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. [gdrimes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6470600/gdrimes) was right. After changing the url from relative:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: FreeSans;
            src: url("./FreeSans.ttf");
        }
```

to absolute

```
@font-face {
            font-family: FreeSans;
            src: url("/home/rok/Documents/Muzey/muzey/website/templates/pdf/FreeSans.ttf");
        }
```

the font in my PDF document was updated.

Comment: tanks bro, this is solution, you are the best

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this thread but I recently had the same problem. The suggestion to use a callback to provide the font definition does work (but in my case case had some limitations because I needed some logic to use different fonts depending on external conditions). However, I found that the problem was that the url("/static/font/swiss.ttf") needs to be an absolute file location, not relative to your application location, as is shown. For example, in my case, my application location was '/home/user/app' the url needs to be:
url("/home/user/app/static/font/swiss.ttf").

Comment: but now i got TTFError at /api/v1/generate-pdf/
Can't open file "C:\Users\bhupesh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5q5lojk0.ttf" error