# Django xhtml2pdf, changing to custom font not working

Tags: python, html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to change the font in my html to pdf project using **xhtml2pdf** (version 0.2.11) in **Django** (version 4.2.2). I'm running the project on my **Windows 11 Home 22H2**, using **python 3.11.0**

Here is how I try to import the font file **html snippet**, but the font did not reflect on the page.

**html snippet**

```
@font-face {
        font-family: Ysabeau Infant;
        src: url('fonts/Ysabeau-Infant.ttf');
}
```

**Views.py**

```
def report_rednder_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    report = get_object_or_404(Report, pk=pk)
    template_path = 'reports/pdf2.html'
    context = {'report': report}
    # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    # If downloadable remove comment
    #response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
    # If viewable remove comment
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'
    # find the template and render it.
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)
    
    # create a pdf
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
       html, dest=response)
    # if error then show some funny view
    if pisa_status.err:
       return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

I tried using the absolute path *C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECT\static\fonts\Ysabeau-Infant.ttf* instead of the relative path, but that did not work, I get the error:

**TTFError**

**Exception Value: Can't open file "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwsd3c9z2.ttf"**

and from the terminal I get the error, **Permission denied: 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwsd3c9z2.ttf'**

I tried running the project as an administrator, and as a user, did not work. Checked the permissions on the **temp** folder, and checked the permission on the font file.

---

I tried also the solution from [@font-face custom font not rendering properly with xhtml2pdf for django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489223/font-face-custom-font-not-rendering-properly-with-xhtml2pdf-for-django) using the function below in the views.py to get the absolute path of the font, but that did not work as well, same error as above:

```
    pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode("UTF-8"), file_object , encoding='UTF-8',
                   link_callback=fetch_resources)
    
    def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
        find_file_in_path_using_uri
        return path
```

I even tried to pass my custom temp folder to the pisa.CreatePDF() function:

```
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF( html, dest=response, link_callback=fetch_resources, path=temp_dir)
```

but that did not help, same error as above, no changes occurred at all.

---

Then I tried using the **{% load static %}** method, where my html looks like this:

```
    {% load static %}
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {...}


        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Ysabeau Infant';
            src: url({% static 'fonts/Ysabeau-Infant.ttf' %});
        }
```

**settings.py**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Nothing happened.

Here is the documentation from the xhtml2pdf website: https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#using-custom-fonts

Comment: i am also faceing same problem how did you manage to fix this !!!

Comment: @bhupeshshakya Still can't find a solution :(

Comment: i found the solution you must add          pisaFileObject.getNamedFile = lambda self: self.uri u must add this monkey patch lol i don't they call it monkey patch though i dont' knwo the reasons
it took me around 10 hours lol we must overide method object so that if store safe as temp upload file gets deleted after some time